# Finding target coordinates from given coordinates

Tags: c, coordinates

Hi their I have an excercise and below is my solution to it. Is their a better solution?

> A figure stands in the 2-dimensional space on coordinate (Fx/Fy) and can move with one step in 8
> directions to a neighboring field: (E SE S SW W NW N NE)
> The figure should move as fast as possible to a target point (Zx/Zy).
> First read the coordinates of the figure and the target point. Then move the figure along the shortest
> possible way to the destination, outputting the coordinates of each step and at the end outputting the number of
> steps required.

What I don't like on the code is how many lines of code I need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fx;
int fy;
int zx;
int zy;
int xgleich = 0;
int ygleich = 0;
int cnt = 1;


// Diagonale Funktion
int diagonalsteps(int fx,int zx)
{
    while (xgleich == 0 && ygleich == 0)
    {
        if (fx < zx)
        {
            fx++;
        }
        else
        {
            fx--;
        }

        if (fy < zy)
        {
            fy++;
        }
        else 
        {
            fy--;
        }
        printf("\n%dter Schritt: X:%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx,fy);
        cnt++;

        if (fx == zx)
        {
            xgleich = 1;
        }
        if (fy == zy)
        {
            ygleich = 1;
        }
    }
}

/* gerader Weg */
int geradesteps(int fy, int zy)
{
    if (xgleich == 1)
    {
        if(fy < zy)
        {
            while (fy < zy)
            {
                fy++;
                printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx, fy);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if (ygleich == 1)
        {
            if (fx < zx)
            {
                while (fx < zx)
                {
                    fx++;
                    printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx, fy);
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if (fx > zx)
            {
                while (fx > zx)
                {
                    fx--;
                    printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx, fy);
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Bitte geben Sie den Koordinaten Fx und Fy Punkt ein: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &fx, &fy);
    printf("%d und %d\n", fx, fy);

    printf("Bitte geben Sie die Ziel Koordinaten Zx und Zy Punkt ein: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &zx, &zy);
    printf("%d und %d\n", zx, zy);

    if (fx == zx)
    {
        xgleich = 1;
    }

    if (fy == zy)
    {
        ygleich = 1;
    }
    diagonalsteps(fx,zx);
    geradesteps(fy,zy);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of lines is what concerns you, you can replace:

```
int fx;
int fy;
int zx;
int zy;
int xgleich = 0;
int ygleich = 0;
int cnt = 1;
```

with

```
int fx, fy, zx, zy, xgleich = 0, ygleich = 0, cnt = 1;
```

and

```
if (fx < zx)
{
    fx++;
}
else
{
    fx--;
}
```

with

```
fx += (fx < zx) ? +1 : -1;
```

The `if` condition is redundant here:

```
if(fy < zy)
{
    while (fy < zy)
```

just use:

```
while (fy < zy)
```

you can also replace

```
if (fx < zx)
{
    while (fx < zx)
    {
        fx++;
        printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx, fy);
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (fx > zx)
{
    while (fx > zx)
    {
        fx--;
        printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt, fx, fy);
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

with

```
int inc = (fx < zx) ? +1 : -1;

while (fx != zx)
{
    fx += inc;
    printf("\n%dter Schritt: X=%d, Y=%d\n", cnt++, fx, fy);
}
```

Finally, compile with warnings, you promise to `return` something from your functions:

```
demo.c: In function ‘diagonalsteps’:
demo.c:46:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   46 | }
      | ^
demo.c: In function ‘geradesteps’:
demo.c:84:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   84 | }
      | ^
```

In this case:

```
void diagonalsteps(int fx,int zx)
```

and

```
void geradesteps(int fy, int zy)
```

is what you want.